# Getting invalid number exception when passing multiple numbers in IN clause as parameter to Oracle query

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Getting invalid number exception when passing multiple numbers as input in `IN` clause as parameter at run time. Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

I have tried it for `string` column its working fine, also tried the same for `number` column by passing the values directly, its working fine. If I pass the values as parameters its not working.

```
Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN (:Param)
```

Passed 1,2,3 as input when it prompts for :Param value. it throws exception.

In cause if i pass the value directly, its working.

```
Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN (1,2,3)
```

I want to filter the data based on number field by passing the number values in `IN` condition at run time. How to achieve this in Oracle.

Comment: `where Id IN (:Param)` gets translated into `where Id IN ('1,2,3')` That does not work. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it work in such a situation then you need to separate those values into columns and then use it in `IN` clause like the following query:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    ID
FROM
    EMPLOYEE
WHERE
    ID IN (
        SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Replace `'1,2,3'` with `:Param` to use it in your code

Cheers!!

Comment: If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

@Tejash's answer is brilliant but the query isn't optimizable. That matters if the `Employee` table will be large.

There's presumably an index/PK on `Employee.Id`. Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` means Oracle will ignore the index and scan the entire `Employee` table looking for the IDs, evaluating `REGEXP_SUBSTR` for each row.

Two optimizable approaches come to mind.

**1. Don't use parameters for the Employee ID list**

I know, sacrilege. But if the Employee ID list is a collection of valid numbers, for example `List<int>`, `int[]`, `IEnumerable<long>`, etc., then the input is cleansed and there's no attack surface for SQL Injection.

```
// employeeIds is the list of IDs; must be vetted as valid numbers
string ids = string.Join(",", employeeIds);
string query = $"Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN ({ids})";
```

Assuming employee IDs 1, 2 and 3, `query` will have the following value:

```
Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

**2. Create a separate parameter for each Employee ID**

Required if the Employee IDs aren't a collection of valid numbers, meaning any of the following:

- Employee IDs can have letters.
- Employee IDs are numbers but they're not validated anywhere.
- Employee IDs are numbers validated on the client side but not the server side.

Note: the code for setting parameter values may vary depending on the data access library used.

```
// employeeIds is a list of IDs; could be any value
int parmNumber = 0;
List<string> parms = new List<string>();
foreach (string id in employeeIds) {
  string parmName = $":id{parmNumber++}"; // id0 or id1 or etc.
  parms.Add(parmName);
  // "command" is the OracleCommand/DbCommand/whatever instance
  command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parmName, id)); 
}
string ids = string.Join(",", parms); // ":id0, :id1, etc."
string query = $"Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN ({ids})";
```

Assuming employee IDs 1, 2 and 3, `query` will have the following value, and the parameter values will be set to 1, 2 and 3 respectively:

```
Select Name, Id from Employee where Id IN (:id0, :id1, :id2)
```